# Generating random numbers and continuing actions

Tags: c++, random

In one assignment I am doing for a beginner C++ class, I am supposed to write a program that tests the user on math skills. I have two problems regarding the thing:

```
void addition(){

srand (50);

int result=0;
int points=0;
int counter=0;

int nbr1 = 100 % rand();
int nbr2 = 100 % rand();

cout<<nbr1<<" + "<<nbr2<<" = ";
cin>>result;

if(result == nbr1+nbr2){
    cout<<"CORRECT";
    points+=10;
    return;
}

if(result !=nbr1+nbr2){
    counter++;
    cout<<"WRONG. TRY AGAIN";
}

if (counter == 1){
    points+=5;
}


if (counter == 2){
    points+=2;
}


if (counter >= 2){
    points=0;
    cout<<" WRONG!The anwser is "<<nbr1+nbr2<<endl;
    return;
}
```

(one function in the code)

Two questions:

1) the numbers the program generated was always 110. Is there a way to keep the numbers random (not always 110 :) and under 100?

2) How can I continue the process of asking questions after one procedure? Now it ends right after the user enters one value:

```
110 + 110 = 220
CORRECT Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To keep the number under 100, you want `rand() %100;` instead of `100 % rand();`

Answer (score 0):

You're always using the same seed for srand, try `srand(time(NULL));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `srand` a different value each time in order to get different numbers, you can use time:

```
#include <time.h>
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to add <time.h>